# What can I do to publish my both application in appcenter in single build in jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, visual-studio-app-center, android-productflavors

I have developed an android application based on flavor, (ie) In single code source I'm getting 2 android application based on flavor. I was able to generate 2 application apk at the same time in single build. But by adding app center plugin in jenkins. I was only able to find the option to upload only one application path to appcenter. **What can I do to publish my both application in appcenter in single build in jenkins?!**

**What can I do to publish my both application in appcenter in single build in jenkins?!**

Comment: hi! did the answer below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a Jenkins scripted pipeline, then you just need to use twice the following code:

```
appCenter apiToken: '...', 
       appName: '...', 
       ownerName: '...', 
       distributionGroups: '...',
       notifyTesters: false, 
       pathToApp: 'app/build/outputs/apk/.../**/*.apk', 
       pathToDebugSymbols: '', 
       releaseNotes: ''
}
```

using valid values for the parameters `apiToken`, `appName`, `ownerName`, `pathToApp` etc.
Once you set them correctly then the AppCenter plugin will update the two apks in the corresponding AppCenter projects.